# WordPress Notice: Undefined variable: post in C:

Tags: php, wordpress

Consider:

```
<?php
    /*
        Portfolio 2 Columns
    */
?>

<?php
    get_header();
?>

<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php
        $terms = get_terms("tagportfolio");
        $count = count($terms);
        echo '<ul id="portfolio-filter">';

            echo '<li><a href="#all" title="">All</a></li>';

            if ( $count > 0 ){

                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                    $termname = strtolower($term->name);
                    $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
                    echo '<li><a href="#' . $termname .
                         '" title="" rel="' . $termname .
                         '">' . $term->name .
                         '</a></li>';
                }
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        ?>

        <?php
            $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
            $count =0;
        ?>

        <div id="portfolio-wrapper">
            <ul id="portfolio-list">

            <?php
                if ( $loop ) :

                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            ?>

            <?php
                        $post = '';

                        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'tagportfolio' );

                        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
                            $links = array();

                            foreach ( $terms as $term )
                            {
                                $links[] = $term->name;
                            }
                            $links = str_replace(' ', '-', $links);
                            $tax = join( " ", $links );
                        else :
                            $tax = '';
                        endif;
            ?>

            <?php
                        $infos = get_post_custom_values('_url');
            ?>

                        <li class="portfolio-item <?php echo strtolower($tax); ?> all">
                            <div class="thumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-large'); ?></a></div>
                            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <p class="excerpt"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></a></p>
                            <p class="links"><a href="<?php echo $infos[0]; ?>" target="_blank">Live Preview →</a> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">More Details →</a></p>
                        </li>

            <?php
                    endwhile; else:
            ?>

                    <li class="error-not-found">Sorry, no portfolio entries for while.</li>

            <?php
                endif;
            ?>

        </ul>

        <div class="clearboth"></div>

    </div> <!-- end #portfolio-wrapper-->

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

I'm getting these notices when debug is true for WordPress code above:

> Notice: Undefined variable: post in C:....php on line 50
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:....php on line 50

Line 50 is:  $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'tagportfolio' );

How can I resolve this issue and get rid of the notice?

Comment: where in your code did you initialize $post and does it have an `ID` property?

Comment: Remove space in **if($terms && ! is_wp_error($terms))** to read **!is_wp_error**

Comment: I've edited code and added this:  $post = ''; to initialize $post and now there is no first notice but second is still there:Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:....on line 50

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line with `$post = '';`. `$post` is a `global` variable.

Then you tried to access the `$post` property *ID*:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'tagportfolio' );
```

This is why you are getting *Undefined variable: post in C:*

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way.

Here it is:

```
global $wp_query;
$post = $wp_query->post;
```

Comment: What is the explanation?